# ¿Hay alguna forma de cambiar la posición donde aparece el selector de color de HTML5?

Tags: html, html5, entrada, color

Me gustaría saber si se puede cambiar el sitio donde aparece el selector de color de html5 por defecto. En esta imagen de ejemplo se puede ver que siempre aparece el selector en la esquina superior izquierda de la página. ¿Esto se puede cambiar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he encontrado la forma de hacerlo ni con algún atributo del input type color ni nada.

Saludos.

Comment: Con css probablemente.

Comment: ¿Qué CSS es el que hay que modificar? Ya que este selector es interno de HTML y no lo he creado yo.

Comment: Ese diálogo es del navegador, cada uno lo mostrará según esté programado.

Comment: El usuario lo puede arrastrar donde quiere que esté. Además creo que aparece donde lo dejó la ultima vez el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente no se puede, la posicion del input de tipo color queda delegada enteramente a la implementación del navegador, no hay nada en la documentación que defina una regla para ello o que indique cómo se puede modificar.

[html - input element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-input-element)

Si para tí es muy importante la posición lo que podrías hacer es implementar tu propio color picker y así podrías posicionarlo, te dejo un link a una librería:

[jscolor](http://jscolor.com/)

Saludos!

Comment: Acuérdate, si usas una librería propia, que no deberás usar `<input type="color"... >` sino `<input type="text"...>` para que el navegador no abra el diálogo propio por defecto.